# Converting to Uppercase adds an extra letter at the end?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert my char array into all uppercases. For some reason, it comes out all uppercase with an extra lowercase letter at the end. (Ex: entering "wow" would have the output "WOWw") I've tried using a for loop and incrementing 'i' with that but that doesn't work either. What's wrong with my code?

```
int i=0;
char c;//added these in just in case I declared it wrong
char a[80], str(50);

while (a[i])
{
    c=a[i];
    putchar (toupper(c));
    i++;
}

cout << c << endl;
```

EDIT: Nevermind, figured it out now. It was a stupid mistake haha.

Comment: One of the best features of C++ is `std::string`. Use that. Avoid using C-style character buffers at every opportunity.

Comment: Tip: Instead of making throw-away variables, just do `putchar(toupper(a[i]))` or even better, use a character pointer: `putchar(toupper(*p))`. When you come up with a working solution, always try and remove any redundant code so long as that doesn't impair understanding. If you're stumped by a bug, removing redundant code is also a good idea as it makes the problem clearer.

Comment: @LeahLeviathan Your edit should have been posted as an answer instead, see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I rolled back the edit, as it invalidated the question.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are explicitly outputting `c` after your loop is done. `c` holds the last character that was processed inside the loop. Simply remove that additional output, you don't need it.

```
while (a[i])
{
    c=a[i];
    //putchar (toupper(c));
    cout << (char) toupper(c);
    i++;
}

cout << /*c <<*/ endl; //<-- here
```

Answer (score 0):

Well because you're printing lower case again after finishing the loop. Simply remove  `cout << c << endl;`. Wow !