# When using toupper() on a character variable, said char variable outputs multiple characters. How would I prevent this?

Tags: c++, string

The intent of the following program is to save a single uppercase character into `testVar`. However, when run, the original character is output alongside the correct character. What causes this, and how would I prevent this occurrence?

```
int main() {
  string userCustom;
  char testVar;

  cout << "Would you like to test a custom square?" << endl;
  cout << "Enter \"yes\" or \"no\"" << endl;
  cin >> userCustom;
  putchar(toupper(userCustom[0]));
  testVar = userCustom.at(0);
  cout << testVar << endl;
}
```

Comment: You ask to print two characters and two characters are printed.

Comment: What's your input & output?

Comment: You're printing the uppercased first character of the string with stdio, and then printing the first character as read with iostreams. Mixing like that works but is a bit unusual to do in the same function.

Comment: Note that `toupper` does not change its argument. You need `testVar = toupper(userCustom[0]);` to get the uppercase character.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], which can be compiled and which doesn't contain anything that's not needed to demonstrate your question. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: `putchar()` and `cout` don't mix too well. Stay with C++ stream IO preferably.

Comment: Are you in the same class as [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863163/converting-to-uppercase-adds-an-extra-letter-at-the-end) asker?

Answer (score 0):

[`putchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/putchar) prints one character and `cout` another one to `stdout`.

To fix you can try this:

```
testVar = toupper(userCustom[0]);

cout<< testVar << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want

```
int main() {
  string userCustom;
  char testVar;

  cout << "Would you like to test a custom square?" << endl;
  cout << "Enter \"yes\" or \"no\"" << endl;
  cin >> userCustom;
  testVar = toupper(userCustom.at(0));
  cout << testVar << endl;
}
```

As Oblivion pointed out, putchar() already prints the toupper() character, but you `cout` the non toupper() character as well as store the wrong one in testVar. You want to store the result of toupper() in testVar

Answer (score 0):

First (uppercase) character is output by putchar function, second - by cout.
To prevent, comment out either putchar, or cout.